# Using > operators in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically, I am trying to create a python program to detect whether the 3 digit number entered by the user is an Armstrong number or not. It's working fine in python, except it's printing the answer 3 times in terminal. But when I use tkinter, I get some problems since I basically just got to know by it just a few hours ago and don't really know how to use it. The problem I get is in > operator, I'm receiving data in Entry() but > operator is for integers so it is giving me type errors.

Here's the error

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Entry'

Here is my code

```
import re
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text="Enter a 3 digit Number")
label.pack()

num = Entry(root, width=50, bg="orangered")
num.pack()

def myclick():
    Sum = 0
    temp = num

    if 1000 > num > 99:
        while temp > 0:
            digit = temp % 10
            Sum += digit ** 3
            temp //= 10
            if num == Sum:
                label2 = Label(root, num, "is an Armstrong number")
                label2.pack()
            else:
                label3 = Label(root, num, "is not an Armstrong number")
                label3.pack()
    else:
        label4 = Label(root,
                       "The number you entered is not a 3 digit number, Please Enter a number between 100 and 999")
        label4.pack()

MyButton = Button(root, text="Click", command=myclick)
MyButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

All I want is to make this program work in a gui, and stop printing the result thrice. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want `int(num.get())`

Comment: `num` is *the Entry widget itself*.  It is not the text that the user typed into the widget, which you would retrieve via `num.get()`.  You would then need to use `int()` or `float()` to turn that text into a number that you can actually perform calculations with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `num` is an `Entry` widget, you cannot use it directly in value comparison.  Use `int(num.get())` to convert the content to an integer number.  You also need to cater invalid input, for example something like "abc", using `try / except`.

Also you create new label (for showing the result) in each iteration of the `while` loop, that is why you get 3 labels for each checking.  It is better to create the result label once outside `myclick()` and update it inside the function instead.

Below is the modified `myclick()`:

```py
def myclick():
    try:
        number = num.get()
        value = int(number)
        if 999 >= value >= 100:
            total = sum(int(digit)**3 for digit in number)
            message = f"{value} {'is' if value == total else 'is not'} an Armstrong number"
        else:
            message = "Enter a number between 100 and 999"
    except ValueError:
        message = f"'{number}' is not a valid number"
    result.config(text=message) # show the result
```

And create `result` label outside the function:

```
result = Label(root)
result.pack()
```